# powershell script error trying to remove-item

Tags: powershell

I have wrote a powershell script that install software.  The script itself works. However, I am trying to modify it to delete the script folder which is copied to the user's desktop (`C:\Script`)

Here is the script

```
 $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName testPC
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Script" -Filter *.exe -Recurse -Verbose -Destination "C:\Script" -ToSession $session | Remove-PSSession
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName testPC -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {start-process "C:\Script\setup.exe" -ArgumentList '/silent' -wait }
    While (Get-Process -Name setup.exe) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
    Remove-Item "C:\Script" -Recurse -Force
```

However, When i run the script. I am given a error message saying ( Cannot remove the item at `C:\Script` because it is in use.  It appears the something has a lock on the directory.  Is there any way to determine what has a lock on the directory? Is there anyway to unlock it?

Comment: PLEASE format your code properly for display here - it is nearly unreadable as is. [*sigh ...*] ///// your `Remove-Item` call seems to be running on the local system ... shouldn't that be removing the one on the remote system?

Comment: Sorry.  I thought i did format it correctly.   Apologies.   How would i modify it to run on the remote system?

Comment: from what little i can read of your code, the `Invoke-Comand` call is already running the script on the remote system. [*grin*] then your last line is removing the master copy on the local system ... and that seems illogical. to remove the remote copy, you would put it in the scriptblock for the I-C call.

Comment: kool! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]